# How to add item in List?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

How to add item in this list?

```
var cl = (from cls in obj.Classes
                   where cls.isDelete != true
                   select new
                   {
                       cls.ID,
                       cls.Name,
                   }).ToList();
```

Comment: I am not really sure what your question is.

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: whatever i get result in "cl" object, i want to add new item in this result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add an item to the list, you can construct a new instance of the anonymous type. The parameter names and types of the new item must *exactly* match the types in the list:

```
cl.Add(new { ID = 123, Name = "abc" });
```

However, this will *not* add a record to the database. In order to do that you'd need something like this:

```
obj.Classes.Add(new MyClass()
{
   Name = "abc"
});

db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: i have try cl.Add(new { ID = 123, Name = "abc" }); but getting error.

Comment: @Hitesh What is the error? Notice what that I said in my answer "The parameter names and types of the new item must exactly match the types in the list".

Comment: error is : Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>.Add(AnonymousType#1)' has some invalid arguments D:\SSS\PaperBuilder\PaperBuilder\SubjectMaster.cs 207 13 PaperBuilder

Comment: One or more of the members of the anonymous type does not match. My answer assumed that `ID` was an int and `Name` was a string. If this is not the case or if there are other members you didn't include in your question, I won't be able to help you without more information.